# Changing values and attribute of collection asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I have this html tags

```
<ul id="ul1" runat=server>
    <li id="li1" runat=server> <a href="link" id="a1" runat=server > <img src="link id="img1" runat=server></img></a></li>
    <li id="li2" runat=server> <a href="link" id="a2" runat=server > <img src="link id="img2" runat=server></img></a></li>
    <li id="li2" runat=server> <a href="link" id="a2" runat=server > <img src="link id="img2" runat=server></img></a></li>
    <li id="li2" runat=server> <a href="link" id="a2" runat=server > <img src="link id="img2" runat=server></img></a></li>
    .
    .
</ul>
```

I am getting the attribute of each control in the "li"  from a xml file.
I want to loop on the the `<li>` collection and change the attribute of each control.
for example:the xml first child is return the src  of the first image,the src of the first `<a>`...
the xml seconed child is return the seconed image src ....

If I tried to do it with jquery, the page is first load the page defult attribute(those who didn't create on the fly)and just after the page is loaded, the "img src" and the 'a href" is changing.

so the only solution is to use server side that change the attribute values before the page is loaded to the client.

I know how to loop on each "li" in "ul" but don't know how to change the attribute of each control with asp.net

Thanks and Any efforts will be appreciated

Comment: Just out of curiosity, can you use a repeater control to render this using the XML file as the data source? Is there a reason that the HTML has to be preset and manipulated using Ladislav's example?

Comment: yes, the reason is that this is a jquery plugin so I can't touch the html code

Comment: So the jQuery plugin is reading the XML and generating the HTML? Or the HTML has to be exactly what's shown above so the jQuery plugin can reference it? Did Ladislav's answer work for this?

Answer (score 0):

You have all controls marked with `runat="server"` so it should be easy task. Something like:

```
HtmlGenericControl ul = this.FindControl("ul1") as HtmlGenericControl;
foreach(HtmlGenericControl li in ul.Controls)
{
     HtmlAnchor a = li.Controls[0] as HtmlAnchor; // add some null validation, etc.
     a.HRef = ...;

     HtmlImage img = a.Controls[0] as HtmlImage; // add some null validation, etc.
     img.Src = ...;
}
```

If you need to do something explicit for some `li` you know their ids so you can again use:

```
// I'm not sure if you will call it on <ul> or page directly - it depends on naming container
HtmlGenericControl li = ul.FindControl("li3") as HtmlGenericControl;
```

Also you can set any attribute of any control derived from `HtmlControl` by calling:

```
control.Attributes["AttributeName"] = value;
```

Comment: Hi Ladislav,thanks for the answer ,I tried your example and it didnt work,I getting error:index was outside of the array(regarding the control[0])

Comment: hi again,ok I manage to do it as you said but the control index is 1 and not 0 (a.Controls[1])